# How do I correctly implement PageFactory annotations within Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, cucumber, page-factory

**What I am trying to do:**

I am currently migrating my Selenium(Java) framework from a standard Page Object model + cucumber setup to a PageFactory + cucumber setup.

**This is what I've done so far to try and make it work:**

- I Initiated my PageFactory.
- I imported all required packages and dependencies.
- I checked multiple online tutorials to make sure I have the right
  syntax.

**The issue I run into:**

My IDEA (IntelliJ) keeps giving me errors on the @FindBy annotations and failing to compile because of it.

When I mouse-over my @FindBy annotations it tells me "@FindBy not applicable to method"

When I try and run my test it gives me the following error on each occurence of the @FindBy annotation.
"annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration"

**The code my question is about:**

```
    package pageObjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class AssociatedAlerts {


    public AssociatedAlerts(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy(css = "#Rabo_SelectedBatchSLTransactionrow0 > * > [type = 'checkbox']")
    public WebElement firstAlertCheckboxSelected();
}
```

I must be missing something simple but I just can't seem to spot it.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your syntax:

```
    @FindBy(css = "#Rabo_SelectedBatchSLTransactionrow0 > * > [type = 'checkbox']")
    public WebElement firstAlertCheckboxSelected();
```

firstAlerchCheckboxSelected is NOT a method. It's a variable.

Change it to:

```
    @FindBy(css = "#Rabo_SelectedBatchSLTransactionrow0 > * > [type = 'checkbox']")
    public WebElement firstAlertCheckboxSelected;
```

Comment: Great catch (+1), Should nail the OP.

Comment: Thank you so much!
It works like a charm now.
And thank you for telling me the why behind it as well.
Lesson learned.

Comment: @Ceesiebird Glad I could help :) You provided the very useful code example. Happy coding!

Comment: @RafałLaskowski so let's say sometimes I wish to give some arguments with my WebElement, which I would normallly define in the () at the end of my method.
How would I go about setting this up given the above code example?

Comment: @Ceesiebird Provide an example because it's too abstract :)

Comment: @Ceesiebird Sorry, but it's not possible. You just have to create a method which finds elements with dynamic/user defined names

Comment: @RafałLaskowski
i.e. If I wish to convert the following: 

`public WebElement attributeValue(String attributeClass){ element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'sectionDetailRow')]/span[contains(@class,'" + attributeClass + "')]")); return element; }`

Into a page factory format like so.

 `@FindBy(xpath = "//td[contains(@class,'sectionDetailRow')]/span[contains(@class,'" + attributeClass + "')]") public WebElement firstAlertCheckboxSelected(String attributeClass);`

When I tried this it gave me the error from the initial question.

Comment: @RafałLaskowski I am not sure what you mean.
Can you please give me an example?

Comment: @Ceesiebird `public WebElement getAlertCheckbox(String attributeClass) {
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'sectionDetailRow')]/span[contains(@class,'" + attributeClass + "')]"));
}`

Comment: Thank you so much @RafałLaskowski